# Why is my chilli seedling dying?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, leaves

All was going well with my Carolina reaper seeds using the baggy method. After it had grown its second pair of leaves I decided to plant it in a pot with some of the paper since the roots had grown through it.

Say two weeks later it hadn't grown very much but looked fine. But when I got home one day the leaves had all dropped down. The day after they're even worse and seem to be curling and maybe slightly yellow.

What's caused this and what can I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: The soil was always this wet?

Comment: @Alina I guess so I spray it a few times everyday

Comment: roots are rotted, pull out and check.

Comment: If the roots aren't rotted, I'd suspect a soil pH issue, a nutrient imbalance, or overfertilization being issues, but yeah, that sounds like too much water, even for misting. How much light did it get?

Comment: Did you amend the soil at all, or add any fertilizer? Seedlings don't typically need it (the cotyledons are fertilizer), but some phosphorus/potassium can be safe for seedlings, as long as you don't add nitrogen with it, and as long as the soil could use those fertilizer combinations. Yellowing cotyledons perhaps might indicate that there's too much potassium in the soil.

Comment: @Shule I have a 40w lamp on it all day, and turn it off at night, it's indoors, but would get some light from the window too.

Comment: @Shule I haven't done anything to the soil, but the soil i bought was 'seed raising' so I assume that means its good for seeds/seedlings

Comment: @Aequitas Some seed-starting mixes aren't so good (at least for peppers). If this happens habitually, I'd try another kind of seed-starting mix (don't give up). Research and find a recommended kind, if possible. I like Nature's brand seedling mix. Worm castings with a little peat moss mixed in can also work.

Comment: Whatever size container you have this growing in, its too large - a seedling that tiny should be in a small pot, then potted on into larger pots as it grows. Keeping it sufficiently well watered  without rotting will be very difficult with that much empty soil round it, and it won't form a good rootball either. Next time you grow, pot your seedlings (when they have two sets of leaves) into small pots first.

Comment: @Bamboo okay will try thanks. I've got a bunch more seeds germinating in another bag. I also have some other ones in smaller pots that are a little smaller (one pair of leaves). This guy was just the first so I could learn from the experience since I don't grow much.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is too much moisture and the seedlings can't absorb it. If the very top of the stem is not wilted, then there might be a chance for the seedlings to stay alive under the condition of reducing the moisture. If the top has wilted as well, there is nothing to be done. Next time when you grow them, moisten the soil only when needed. Too wet soil promotes rot in addition to overwhelming the root system of small plants.

Comment: The stem is not wilted at all, it's quite sturdy so i'll stop watering it and we'll see how it goes. Do you think it was a bad idea to plant it with the paper? as that probably retains some more moisture then it would otherwise.

Comment: A sturdy/strong/tough stem is a sign that the plant has a good supply of potassium. If there are lots of wood chips in the soil, they can add a lot of potassium and calcium (potentially too much).

Comment: @Aequitas Not necessarily bad to plant with the paper, but also not optimum. Many books teach us to keep the soil moist in permanence, but in my experience this is risky. If you have more than one container, next time try to mist one of them less and by watching them grow you'll figure how much moisture is best.

Comment: @Shule Thanks for sharing this, I didn't know about it. I don't fertilize my seedlings and I use regular potting soil instead of special starter mix because it has worked perfectly so far, so I' not familiar with symptoms of fertilized seedlings.